# Is it a good idea to introduce myself to my potential supervisor with the current employee of the organization who referred me?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, applications

One of my references (who is a current employee at the organization I applied to) suggested me that she can take me to meet my potential supervisor so that I can introduce myself, if I want to. Is this a good idea? The organization is very firm about their policy that every applicants should apply via their website, and the applications will be received through their website only. I already did apply through their website, and I am wondering if such "meeting" will do me good. With 100% certainty the organization will hire internal candidates over external candidates of same qualification.

My only worry is that if the supervisor have negative impression about me because she thinks I am trying to get a job through the connection only. But I am one of the qualified candidate for the job, and my qualification even exceeds what is stated in the job posting (but not by too much that they will think I am overqualified for the positing).

Should I take her suggestion? or would it be better if my reference refer me to my potential supervisor without me seeing the supervisor?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend against it.  If the organisation has clear governance rules around recruitment, you are more likely to hinder rather than help your chances of getting the job.  Let the internal person sing your praises to the manager, do the interview(s) to the best of your ability and hopefully you will land the job.

If you really must, you can mention the internal contact in the interview, but I'd state it something along the lines of "Person X works for your organisation, she said that it was a great place to work so I am particularly interested in this role."

I've worked for a number of government and large organisations who have strict governance guidelines around such things.  Just let your contact say what she will to the manager and reduce the risk of being caught up in a recruitment process conflict.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I shouldn't have the meeting, would it be a good idea to mention my connection in my cover letter (I.e. write a referral cover letter), just to help my application to pass through the initial screening process? I am applying to a regional hospital, which functions more or less like government or any other public institutions. Thank you,

Comment: I wouldn't mention it in a cover letter.  As in my answer, you can informally mention in an interview that you  know someone who works there and they told you that it was a great place to work, but otherwise it would be very out of place on a cover letter.